# Creating checkboxes in HTML / PHP?

Tags: php, html, forms

So I have the following code.

My main.html form lets me enter a value (a price for pc) and when I submit it calls the pcs.php script which displays all my pcs under the given value/price.

But I want to have an checkbox beside the information displayed by the script. ie

```
<br>alienware, 3000, gtx760 checkbox <br>  asus rog, 2500, radeodhdxxxx checkbox <br>
```

and so on).

//main.html

```
 <BODY> 
 <FORM METHOD="POST" ACTION="pcs.php" >
  <INPUT TYPE='textbox' NAME='mypc' VALUE='' >
  <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" NAME="Button" VALUE="Hit me"> 
  </FORM> </BODY> </HTML>
```

//pcs.php

```
<?php
$dd = $_POST['mypc'];


$filename = "computer.txt";
$filepointer = fopen($filename,"r");  
$myarray = file ($filename);
for ($mycount = 0; $mycount < count($myarray); $mycount++ )
{           

  $apc = $myarray[$mycount];  
  $price = getvalue($apc,1);
  $part = explode(',', $apc);
  //print $price ."<br>";
  //print $str ."<br>";
  if ($str <$dd ) 
    { 
      for($pcount = 0; $pcount<3; $pcount++) {
       print $part[$pcount] ."<br>";

    }
     print "<br>";

 }


}


 function getvalue ($text, $commaToLookFor)
 {   
 $intoarray = explode(",",$text);
  return  $intoarray[ $commaToLookFor];  
}

// fclose ($filepointer);


 ?> 


 <p>

 </body>
 </html>
```

// computer.txt file

```
alienware, 3000, gtx760<br>
asus rog, 2500, radeonhdxxx<br>
alienware, 5000, gtx titan<br>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate, please?

Comment: Are you simply looking to add `echo "<input type='checkbox'/>"` in your loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pcs.php you'll just need to modify your for loop to look something like:

```
// Create form
print '<form method="post" action="script_to_post_to.php">';    

for ($mycount = 0; $mycount < count($myarray); $mycount++) {           
  $apc = $myarray[$mycount];  
  $price = getvalue($apc,1);
  $part = explode(',', $apc);

  if ($str < $dd) { 
    for($pcount = 0; $pcount<3; $pcount++) {
      print $part[$pcount] ."<br>";
    }

    // Add checkbox and name with product type
    print '<input type="checkbox" name="' . getvalue($apc, 2) . '" />';
    print "<br>";
  }
}

// Provide form submission button and close form element
print '<input type="submit" value="Submit" />';
print '</form>';
```

You'll have a form with each element having a checkbox and the ability to respond to the list of checked items in "script_to_post_to.php".

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but now I have another question. I want to make the checkbox an array  and then when i call the script if I want to display the elements that were checked ?I i name the checkboxes differently it works but if i make to an array it does not.